# Working with lists and adding elements

Tags: list

in C#  if I declare a new list say, myList, can I add items to that list later at a specific index location like this, myList[2] = 42. And can I then write over that index location again without first deleting it by doing myList[2] = 28?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will give you ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an array would be a better choice.